# How to connect to backend server using API in angularjs ionic

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I have been trying to connect to the backend server using $http requests in ionic angularjs. I want to register a user using the API. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code? This is my controller.js

```
angular.module('app.Auth', [])

.factory('Auth', ['$q', '$http', '$localStorage', 'URL', function($q, $http, $localStorage, URL) {

return {
    register: function(data, success, error) {
        $http.post(URL.api + 'register', data).success(success).error(error)
    }
};
}])
.controller('SignupCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk,Auth,$localStorage,$state,Auth,URL) {

$scope.signupError = function(msg){
    if(msg.status == false){
        $scope.errors = msg.errors;
    }else{
        $scope.errors = ['Error accessing API.'];
    }
};


$scope.signupSuccess = function(response){
    if(response.status==false){
        $scope.errors = response.errors;
    }else{
        alert("success!");
    }

};

$scope.user = {
    firstname:'',
    middlename:'',
    lastname:'',
    password: '',
    email: ''
};

$scope.signupEmail = function(){
    Auth.register($scope.user,$scope.signupSuccess,$scope.signupError);
};
});
```

and this is my signup.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign Up" name="signup">
<ion-content>
  <div class="list">
   <div ng-if="errors.length > 0" class="error_bg" ng-repeat="error in errors">
            <p class="error" ng-bind="error"></p>
        </div>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" style="color:purple; font-size:18px" ng-model="user.firstname">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">Middle Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" style="color:purple; font-size:18px" ng-model="user.middlename">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" style="color:purple; font-size:18px" ng-model="user.lastname">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">Email Address</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" style="color:purple; font-size:18px" ng-model="user.email">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" style="color:purple; font-size:18px" ng-model="user.password">
    </label>
    </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-royal" style="background-color:blue" ng-click="signupEmail()">Continue</button>
```

Comment: You will have to provide more information.  What is the problem you are encountering?  If you just don't know how to use $http, there are plenty of examples out there.  If you're getting an error, post the error and the code that's causing it.

Comment: ok i have added the details :)

Comment: It's still not clear what your issue is.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I just want to know that am i doing it right? coz i dont get the success alert. or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the right sintax of [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

In fact, `$http.post()` returns a **promise** which has the method `then()` with two arguments (succcess and error handlers), so your HTTP request to register service should be rewritten from:

```
$http.post(URL.api + 'register', data).success(success).error(error);
```

to:

```
$http.post(URL.api + 'register', data).then(success, error);
```

For promises in Angular see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: ok now i am using this but it returns error

$http.post(url, {params:{first_name:'zeeshan'}}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    alert(response.data);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert('error')
   alert(response.data);
     });

Comment: I dont get any data. i get null in repsonse

Comment: So 'response' or 'response.data' is null? And what about the console log (Chrome), "network" tab? What's the http status code and the response from server?